# Can I use PVC pipe to extend a bathroom exhaust duct outside the wall?

Tags: hvac, bathroom, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent, venting

I have a new bathroom in my basement which is completely below grade. The duct for the bath vent was routed out through the joist space to the exterior wall and a vent wall cap added. The bottom of the vent is actually a couple inches below the grade outside. I’ve dug down and retained a bit to provide clearance, but I’d like to vent it out a bit higher.

There is no cavity in the exterior wall which is solid brick and only has furring and gyp on the inside so can’t fit a duct in the wall behind on the first floor. Can I use PVC and gooseneck up and out? It won’t look pretty, but would it work? I have concerns with condensation and freezing in Chicago. The outdoor water spigot shared the same joist space.

Comment: _I'd like to vent it out a bit higher._ Why? A deeper excavation seems like a much simpler and less failure-prone (let alone less ugly) approach. Consider it just like a basement window.

Comment: A subsurface window usually has no alternative, and is a least-worst solution. This does have an easy alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be afraid to try it, with a few stipulations:

- Put a weep hole in a low point. Condensation shouldn't be able to drain back into the home. I don't know if I'd do a full-on P-trap, but maybe a hole just downstream of a coupling joint at the wall line.
- Put 1/4" mesh in the opening. You don't want *creatures* using it as a skyway or a nest box.
- Be sure it's supported and protected from impact. Considering the probable unwelded joint at the wall line it'll need physical security.
- Terminate horizontally or downward to avoid catching rain.

I won't address building code because I don't know it. I don't think there's any real danger to health or property presented here.